# How to collect xcode log?

Tags: xcode, logging, bug-reporting

I file a bug to Apple through their bug report. Now they ask me send log.

How to collect xcode log? I have system log and console log ready.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe Xcode writes a dedicated log file. However, the Console app should have everything you need (you'd need to filter by PROCESS|Xcode to see only Xcode entries).

Alternatively, starting Xcode from the terminal window (via `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`) should produce only Xcode logs.

Please see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232946/how-to-get-logs-for-the-xcode-application/46674772#46674772) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect an Xcode sysdiagnose log using the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo sysdiagnose Xcode
```

This presents the following information:

> This tool generates files that allow Apple to investigate issues with your computer and help improve Apple products. The files might
>    contain personal information found on your device or associated with
>    your iCloud accounts, including but not limited to your name, serial
>    numbers of your device, your device name, your attached peripheral
>    devices, your user name, your email address and email settings, file
>    paths, file names, Siri suggestions, your computer's IP addresses, and
>    network connection information.
>
> This information is used by Apple in accordance with its privacy
>    policy (www.apple.com/privacy) and is not shared with any other
>    company. By using this tool and sending the results to Apple, you
>    consent to Apple using the contents of these files to improve Apple
>    products.

The process can take up to 10 minutes to complete.

The resulting `tar.gz` file will be found in `/private/var/tmp` when completed and can be 100's of Mbs in size.

Answer (score -1):

- Connect the iPad or iPhone to the Mac and sync it as usual
- Hit Command+Shift+G and navigate to
  ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/
- For those with multiple iOS devices, select the proper device that
  you want to retrieve the crash log from
- Look for files with the app name you want the crash reports from,
  copy that out of the folder, or copy multiple logs and zip them up
  for the developer

Comment: I think I have a different issue. My Xcode can't start Apple Watch Extension, I file a bug with Apple and want to get Xcode log and attach it to the report. Thanks for the reply!!