# How to get logs for the XCode application

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, crash-reports, xcode-storyboard

I'm looking for logs of the Xcode application itself.  Not logs of my iOS app or device.

I've been doing a bit of experimental work with the storyboard source code xml.  Sometimes I'll get a random crash of Xcode or a message like "The document Main.storyboard' could not be opened.  Could not verify document content"  (This is not git conflict related)

I'd like to look in the logs to see if it gives a clue as to what part of the xml is causing these crashes or errors.

Note: I was able to find some additional crash information by looking in the 'console' app.  But not error information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things here. First of all, I do not believe Xcode writes any dedicated log files (as opposed to, say, Android Studio, that puts logs under ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio2.2). Having said that, there are a couple of places to get them:

**1. The device logs**

Xcode uses system logging to log its messages to the console. If you open the Console app, find your macOS device in the Devices list and look at the messages. By default, it shows all the messages from all the apps, but you can filter our by PROCESS - Xcode (filtering is a bit unintuitive, you first search for Xcode which generates ANY|Xcode filter, than you select ANY and change it to PROCESS).

The one problem with the Console app on macOS Sierra is that it only shows logs from when you started the Console app, not earlier. You can use the `log` command line to collect previous logs (e.g. `sudo log collect --last 1d`). You can find more information about it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278393/sierra-console-app-show-earlier-data).

Alternatively, you can actually start Xcode from the terminal (by typing `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode` in the terminal window). If you do that, all the logs will be written to the terminal console.

**2. The Diagnostic Reports**

These (also accessible via the Console app) will contain crashes that Xcode itself doesn't log (there are some cases where Xcode will die silently, but the Diagnostics Reports may still contain the error along with the callstack and other useful info). Note that there are two places where Diagnostic Reports are stored, under ~/Library/Logs and /Library/Logs - make sure to check both.